# Check if two files are the same in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get the bibliographic information of the currently open PDF in Skim.
To do that, I am comparing the file to the linked files of all the publications I have in BibDesk.
But for some reason, that comparison doesn't work:

```
tell application "Skim"
    set theFile to the file of the front document

    tell application "BibDesk"
        repeat with currentPub in publications of front document
            set bibFile to linked file of currentPub
            if bibFile = theFile then
                say "lala"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

The script does get both theFile and bibFile correctly, but comparing them doesn't work. Why is that and what do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's super easy: you just have to compare with `as string`:

```
tell application "Skim"
    set theFile to the file of the front document

        tell application "BibDesk"
            repeat with currentPub in publications of front document
                set bibFile to linked file of currentPub
                if bibFile as string = theFile as string then
                    say "lala"
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
end tell
```